# Using multiple sdk versions in my project

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am currently working on an app using some features that are only accessible in android 9.

I want to distinguish between users that have android 9 and can thereby use these features and users that are on 8.1 or lower for which I have to find an alternative solution.

Based on this information I want to call either the version with the features coming with android 9 or an alternative version that every smartphone can use.
My question now is, is it possible to create a project that contains android 9 "classes" but never get called when the device it is running on is 8.1 or lower.
Or is it not even possible to compile this project for a SDK version below android 9.

I am thankful for every answer.

Comment: In addition to Mark's answer, you can annotate your risky methods with @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P) so whenever in your code you want to use those methods, Android Studio will warn you that you should check version before doing it.

Comment: Alright thanks,
did not know that about android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the Build version like this...

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) ...
```